# Problems with Slick carousel centerMode - Growing center item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I am implementing Ken Wheeler's slick carousel and having some trouble with styling the center item.

In the demo for centerMode:true on his site the center tile is bigger than the other tiles.

I also want to implement it in this way but when I apply custom styling to the center item to increase its size the animation of the carousel becomes very jumpy and unstable.

My HTMl looks like this:

```
<div class="main-carousel">
        <div class="tile-container">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/course_images/course-image-1.jpg").url" alt="logo" class="tile-image">
        </div>
        <div class="tile-container">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/course_images/course-image-2.jpg").url" alt="logo" class="tile-image">
        </div>
        <div class="tile-container">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/course_images/course-image-1.jpg").url" alt="logo" class="tile-image">
        </div>
        <div class="tile-container">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/course_images/course-image-1.jpg").url" alt="logo" class="tile-image">
        </div>
        <div class="tile-container">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/course_images/course-image-2.jpg").url" alt="logo" class="tile-image">
        </div>
        <div class="tile-container">
            <img src="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/course_images/course-image-1.jpg").url" alt="logo" class="tile-image">
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am working with images conained within divs. Here is my CSS:

```
.slick-current img{
  width: 350px !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
}

.tile-container img{
  width: 284px;
}

.tile-container img{
  padding-top: 20px ;
}

.tile-container{
  padding: 5px;
}
```

And finally my slick initiation script looks like this:

```
$('.main-carousel').slick({
     centerMode:true,
     centerPadding: '80px',
     slidesToShow: 4,
     slidesToScroll: 1,
     infinite: true,
     variableWidth: true,
     variableHeight: true
 });
```

It also looks like the centerPadding is not being applied - that's why I'm manually adding the styling to grow the center tile.

To summarize : The only issue I'm actually having is that the carousel's animation is jumpy when I apply the styles for growing the center tile.

I am using jQuery 3.1.1 as well as jquery-migrate. All the required styles for the carousel are also imported.

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b3cfooz5/

Comment: Hello Zenith, can you share a JSFiddle or maybe your dev website ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to spin one up. Here you go https://jsfiddle.net/b3cfooz5/

Answer (score 2):

Solved it. I used

```
 transform: scale(1.08);
```

to scale the center item up rather than resizing it with pixel width.

Here's to hoping someone in the future runs into the same issue and finds this thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with css

```
 .slider img{
           margin: 0 auto;
        }
```